# i2c-tools does not appear to be installed after adding it in local.conf

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I am new to YOCTO and am trying to install the i2c-tools in an image for the Raspberry Pi 3, but I don't seem to be able to get it working.

I put CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " i2c-tools" in the local.conf file and then build the image with bitbake "core-image-base".

But when I boot it, it doesn't seem to be installed anywhere. Am I doing something wrong here?

I have also used IMAGE_INSTALL and EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURE, but they do not work either.

Comment: did you tried to add it to only one image ( into .bb file) , not to all of them (into conf/local.conf) ?

Comment: My bad, I already solved it but forgot about the question here. It wasn't doing it but after a complete clear it magically worked so there is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I erased every file created when built and recompiled and it magically worked. Problem solved I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "dev-pkgs debug-tweaks"
```

I need to add password for root user also because after adding dev-pkgs, while booting it asked for password.

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P password root;
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer according to [answer]? It gives more of an impression of describing what you want to achiebe, what your problem is and of a request for help with your problem. Please [edit] to make more obvious what the solution is you propose.